# Codeigniter: uploading images with resize 300x300 (maintain ratio is mentioned false).. but rectangle images getting narrow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

Codeigniter: uploading images with resize 300x300 (maintain ratio is mentioned false).. but rectangle images getting narrow

I am uploading images in codeigniter with 300x300 resize, maintain ratio - false

but some images (rectangle images) getting narrow

my code snippet (some part of code):

```
....
....
$config['create_thumb']   = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config['new_image']    = './uploads/property/300X300/';
$config['width']       = 300;
$config['height']       = 300;
$this -> image_lib -> initialize($config);
$this -> image_lib -> resize();
....
....
```

please suggest me the changes to show uploaded images 300x300 to front end with proper view

you may suggest css if possible it through css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css:

```
.yourclass {
    height:250px;
    display:flex;
    flex-shrink:0;
    max-width:98%;
    max-height:98%;
}
```

you can modify class inner values as per your requirements

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand PHP/Codeigniter more, but have you tried this on CSS?

```
.your-name-class{
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```